# Android SQLite DB location

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Is it possible to store my applications SQLite database in some other location that I define instead of the default /data/data//databases location?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need that? that's a pitfall.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) might be helpful. It demonstrates how to store a db in the assets folder of your app, (though all it does is copy over the db to a /data/databases database, so I'm not sure if that will help your situation.)

Could you give a little more context as to why you want to store your database elsewhere?